# Round values depend rounding value

Tags: php, rounding

if use round() , you will round up if number higher than 0.5 and round down if number less than 0.5, i have a condition if you round higher than 0.3 it will round up and less than 0.3 it will round down.

```
<?php 
//normal round
echo round(3.4);         // 3
echo round(3.5);         // 4
echo round(3.6);         // 4

//round i want
echo round(3.34);         // 4
echo round(3.29);         // 3
echo round(3.3);          // 3
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what were the results? Please read about _asking_ in the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Add code snippets of what you tried and what problems you are facing. SO is not a code writing service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own rounding-function, where you get the fraction of the number by subtracting the floored number from itself, then compare that against your limit.

```php
function my_round($value, $round_up_from = 0.3) {
    $fraction = $value - floor($value);  // Get the fraction
    if ($fraction >= $round_up_from) {   // If the fraction is equal to or above threshold, ceil it
        return ceil($value);
    }
    return floor($value);                // Otherwise, floor it
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/Uo0vK